# cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'system.collections.arraylist' in C#

Tags: c#

Here is my code :

```
XmlNodeList ProjectNode = DOC.GetElementsByTagName("AppBuilderProject");

foreach (XmlNode AllNodes in ProjectNode) 
{
    Project.Titel = AllNodes["Titel"].InnerText; // 1st value from node

    foreach (XmlNode controlsform in Project.Forms) // arraylist Forms
    {
        Project.Forms = controlsform["forms"].InnerText;// error
    }
}
```

Please tell me how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Project.Forms is of type system.collections.arraylist but you are trying to copy a string to it.  I'm guessing that your `project.forms =` is supposed to be something else.  Can you explain what you are trying to do

Comment: What you are trying to does not make sense. The error tells you exactly what the problem is.  You are trying to perform an illegal cast from `System.Collections.ArrayList` to `String` this cannot be done.

Comment: A few things, I mean this in the politest way possible: "Titel" is spelled "Title". What is a Project object? Your error indicates that you are implicitly converting a string to an ArrayList which is a no no. You can't do that. If there is a serialized object in the InnerText, then it needs to be deserialized back into your desired object. I would avoid using an ArrayList btw, use generics List<T>, but in cases of serialization using a plain array will be what you need anyhow.

Comment: @BobVale: i am trying to take values from class FBprojects which have 2 properties. Titel and Forms(arraylist).
and forms have controls. basically i want to create UI at runtime from XML file

Comment: What UI? I'm betting ASP, that'd make a remote kind of sense. Your project seems a little far fetched though. If it indeed is ASP you're far better off selecting between a set of user controls and binding data in those.

Comment: @HmXa but you are trying to re-update Project.Forms whilst reading its values.... Is this what you intended?

Comment: @BobVale: can i send you a sample of my project.?

Comment: @HmXa If you sent me the project then other people trying to answer this question or who have similar problems wouldn't have all the information.  You need to update your question to contain all the pertinent information

Comment: OK i will elaborate my question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property  "Project.Forms" is obviously of type arraylist and property (XmlNode).InnerText is string

Try this

```
if(Project.Forms == null) Project.Forms = new ArrayList();
Project.Forms.Add(controlsform["forms"].InnerText);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be `Project.Forms.Add(controlsform["forms"].InnerText)`

Comment: Sorry, typing mistake :) I repaired that